# Finding the absolute minimum of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\sin x$

Tags: trigonometry, maxima-minima

For the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\sin x$, the domain is $\mathbb{R}-\left\{0\right\}$, but how do I analytically determine the range of the function? Since it's not $[-1,1]$.

Graph:

[image]

Comment: Can't you just determine the maxima and minima by taking the derivative?

Comment: The function has a lot of local maxima and minima, so then how could you determine which one is the absolute maximum/minimum?

Comment: You should search for the closest to zero point where the derivative is zero. This means the closest to zero solutions of $\tan (x) = x$.

Comment: I could do that, but how do you know that the absolute minimum is close to zero?

Comment: From your graphic

Comment: Oh I forget to mention, in this case I don't have access to the graph, all I got to work with is the function.

Comment: You'd have to solve $tan(x)=x$ analytically, which I believe is not possible. I'm not sure though.

Comment: I think that's possible using Taylor series, but I was wondering if there was another way...

Comment: What do you mean by " in this case I don't have access to the graph", you just post it

Comment: Yes, but in the course I am taking, we need to solve these kind of problems without using calculators that can draw graphs.

Comment: Just pretend you didn't see the graph :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $f(x)={\displaystyle \sin x\over x}$. Note that $f(x)$ is an even function (its graph is symmetric about the $y$-axis). Note also that 
$$|f(x)|<{1\over 2\pi} \qquad \mbox{ for } |x|>2\pi.$$
Now it remains to analyze only a couple of local extrema points with $|x|\le2\pi$ and confirm that the one with $x\approx4.49$ is indeed the global minimum, with $f(x)<-{1\over2\pi}$. (You will get two minimum points which are symmetric about the $y$-axis.)

Comment: how do we find those? By taking the derivative?

Comment: Yes. We analyze local extrema by taking the derivative, which is $f'(x)={x\cos x - \sin x\over x^2}$. Now we just find those $x$ where $f'(x)$ is zero, and determine which of them are indeed minima.

Comment: The function is $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. The derivative is $\frac{\cos(x)}{x}-\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}=\frac{x\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{x^2}$, so the limit points are found at the solutions to $\tan(x)=x$ I have had trouble with this exact equation before.

Comment: Actually $\tan(x)=x$ has a unique solution in $(0, 2\pi)$

Comment: But there is no way to analytically solve tan(x) = x right?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: @Eugen In fact $\tan(x) =x$ has three solutions when $-2\pi<x<2\pi$. When you cannot solve analytically, do it numerically.

Comment: @Alex I don't think so, it's only x=4.49340945790906 in $(0, 2\pi)$

Comment: @Eugen You and I are both right. Three solutions in $(-2\pi,2\pi)$ while only one solution in $(0,2\pi)$.

Comment: I'll try to do it numerically, thank you guys!